# Joining two LEFT JOINS Together

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to combine these two LEFT JOINS together.

Preview of tables I am working with:

For example/context:

Table Name: [GMC Claims 2019]

| PatNo | RevCode | CPT | BilledCharges | DRG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 141 | null | 500 | 439 |
| 5 | 636 | J1234 | 276000 | 101 |

Table Name: BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS

| DRG Code | Description | DRG Weight | ALOS | High Trim | Effective Date | DRG Rate | Per Diem High Trim Outlier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | XXXXX | YYYYY | 30 | 54 | 10/1/2018 | $235,121.59 | $5,486.17 |
| 101 | XXXXX | YYYYY | 24 | 40 | 10/1/2018 | $146,736.72 | $4,279.82 |
| 439 | XXXX | YYYYY | 13 | 23 | 10/1/2018 | $63,124.34 | $3,399.00 |

Table Name: [BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016]

| DRG | SERVICE | PMT (SDA) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | DRG CARVE OUT | 13537 |
| 439 | DRG CARVE OUT | 13537 |

Desired Output:

| DRG | DRG Reimbursement | Carve Out PMT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 439 | $63,124.34 | 13537 |
| 101 | $146,736.72 | 13537 |

The logic is, given the claims table as our main table, find the DRG codes that match (101 & 439 in this case) and return the respective values (so DRG Reimbursement from the BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS table and Carve Out PMT from the [BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016] table.

My code/attempt:

```
SELECT
    [GMC Claims 2019].DRG
FROM
    [GMC Claims 2019]
LEFT JOIN 
    [BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016] ON [GMC Claims 2019].DRG = [BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016].DRG
WHERE
    [GMC Claims 2019].DRG = [BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016].DRG
LEFT JOIN 
    BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS ON [GMC Claims 2019].DRG = BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.DRG_Code
WHERE
    [GMC Claims 2019].DRG = BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.DRG_Code
```

Comment: Markdown is killing me today...question shows tables correctly in preview but not when I post..

Comment: I emailed you! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think inner join between three tables will server your purpose:

```
select c.drg, b.Per_Diem_High_Trim_Outlier, d.pmt
from  [GMC Claims 2019] c 
inner join [BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS] b on c.drg = b.drg_code 
inner join [BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016] d on d.drg = b.drg_code
```

Comment: It does indeed serve my purposes, thanks!. Is there a way to achieve the same out without hardcoding in the 439,101 ? Dataset has ~1 million rows so I'm trying to avoid hardcoding if possible.

Comment: Just remove the condition. Then this query will return all the rows that fulfill joining condition.

Answer (score 1):

when you join , there is condition that you join on, there is no need for where clause , unless there is a reason, however in you case you need inner join not outer join:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [GMC Claims 2019]
JOIN BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS 
        ON [GMC Claims 2019].DRG = BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.DRG_Code
JOIN [BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016]  -- < here maybe it should be left join ?
        ON [GMC Claims 2019].DRG = [BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016].DRG
```

Comment: by the way these are the worst naming an object

Comment: I should use aliases right to make it cleaner? Also, what you gave me makes sense but doesn't return DRG 101 which shows up in all 3 tables. It repeats DRG 439 twice. Thanks for your time by the way!

Comment: still name of those tables/view stay like that , anyways , for 101 case , maybe you don't have data in "[BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016]" table, in that case you need to use left join